# Как объединить два exe файла в один?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, многопоточность, cmd, exe

У меня есть два файла, один файл - script, который записывает определенные данные в файл log.txt, а также есть второй файл - bot, который берет информацию из файла log.txt и присылает в чат, как объеденить script и bot чтобы они запускались и работали одновременно?

Comment: Один вопрос: зачем? Если их изначально не объединили в один модуль, теперь это во-первых бессмысленно, во-вторых — вряд ли возможно. Если вам так надо — напишите коротенькую прогу, вызывающую эти два экзешника, и все.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий!